# Using gstreamer to record an m3u8 stream

Tags: gstreamer, recording, m3u8

I'm trying to use gstreamer to record a video stream for a url, https://csm-e-nineau2-eb.bln1.yospace.com/csm/extlive/nnaprd01,prod-simulcast-mel-ch9-hls-r13.m3u8

I have managed to do this with a test stream, http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/gear4/prog_index.m3u8, that's on the gstreamer examples page using the following command (using fakesink here for testing)

```
 gst-launch-1.0 souphttpsrc location=http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/gear4/prog_index.m3u8 \
 ! hlsdemux \
 ! tsdemux \
 ! queue \
 ! video/x-h264 \
 ! h264parse \
 ! fakesink
```

When I try the exact same command with the stream I want, I receive the following error:

```
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstHLSDemux:hlsdemux0: Internal data stream error.
Additional debug info:
../gst-libs/gst/adaptivedemux/gstadaptivedemux.c(3891): gst_adaptive_demux_stream_download_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstHLSDemux:hlsdemux0:
streaming stopped, reason not-linked (-1)
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstHLSDemux:hlsdemux0: Internal data stream error.
Additional debug info:
../gst-libs/gst/adaptivedemux/gstadaptivedemux.c(3891): gst_adaptive_demux_stream_download_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstHLSDemux:hlsdemux0:
streaming stopped, reason not-linked (-1)
```

I'm struggling here to work out what my issue here is with the stream, and what I should be linking the hlsdemux to. Running a get-discover on the url gives me the following:

```
gst-discoverer-1.0 -v https://csm-e-nineau2-eb.bln1.yospace.com/csm/extlive/nnaprd01,prod-simulcast-mel-ch9-hls-r13.m3u8
Analyzing https://csm-e-nineau2-eb.bln1.yospace.com/csm/extlive/nnaprd01,prod-simulcast-mel-ch9-hls-r13.m3u8
Done discovering https://csm-e-nineau2-eb.bln1.yospace.com/csm/extlive/nnaprd01,prod-simulcast-mel-ch9-hls-r13.m3u8

Properties:
  Duration: 99:99:99.999999999
  Seekable: yes
  Live: no
  Tags:
      private-data: buffer of 8 bytes
      nominal bitrate: 128025
      audio codec: MPEG-4 AAC
      video codec: H.264
  container #0: application/x-hls
    Tags:
      None

    container #-1: video/mpegts, systemstream=(boolean)true, packetsize=(int)188
      Tags:
        None

      video #1: video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)avc, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, width=(int)854, height=(int)480, framerate=(fraction)25/1, coded-picture-structure=(string)frame, chroma-format=(string)4:2:0, bit-depth-luma=(uint)8, bit-depth-chroma=(uint)8, colorimetry=(string)bt709, parsed=(boolean)true, alignment=(string)au, profile=(string)high, level=(string)3, codec_data=(buffer)0164001effe100272764001eac72100d83de6f016a020202800000030080000019747003a9801d4d7bdc07c201092001000428fb8f2c
        Tags:
          video codec: H.264

        Codec:
          video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)avc, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, width=(int)854, height=(int)480, framerate=(fraction)25/1, coded-picture-structure=(string)frame, chroma-format=(string)4:2:0, bit-depth-luma=(uint)8, bit-depth-chroma=(uint)8, colorimetry=(string)bt709, parsed=(boolean)true, alignment=(string)au, profile=(string)high, level=(string)3, codec_data=(buffer)0164001effe100272764001eac72100d83de6f016a020202800000030080000019747003a9801d4d7bdc07c201092001000428fb8f2c
        Stream ID: a4b40f2cfad0e90e410cdb6ae232e3f77caacc14e61a67041b21641c1866aa91/src_0:1/000001e1
        Width: 854
        Height: 480
        Depth: 24
        Frame rate: 25/1
        Pixel aspect ratio: 1/1
        Interlaced: false
        Bitrate: 0
        Max bitrate: 0
    container #-1: audio/mpeg, framed=(boolean)false, mpegversion=(int)4, stream-format=(string)adts, level=(string)2, base-profile=(string)lc, profile=(string)lc, channels=(int)2, rate=(int)48000
      Tags:
        None

      audio #2: audio/mpeg, framed=(boolean)true, mpegversion=(int)4, level=(string)2, base-profile=(string)lc, profile=(string)lc, rate=(int)48000, channels=(int)2, stream-format=(string)adts
        Tags:
          private-data: buffer of 8 bytes
          nominal bitrate: 128025
          audio codec: MPEG-4 AAC

        Codec:
          audio/mpeg, framed=(boolean)true, mpegversion=(int)4, level=(string)2, base-profile=(string)lc, profile=(string)lc, rate=(int)48000, channels=(int)2, stream-format=(string)adts
        Stream ID: a4b40f2cfad0e90e410cdb6ae232e3f77caacc14e61a67041b21641c1866aa91/src_1
        Language: <unknown>
        Channels: 2 (front-left, front-right)
        Sample rate: 48000
        Depth: 32
        Bitrate: 128025
        Max bitrate: 0
```

**EDIT:** It looked like the hlsdemux was failing due to there being multiple video streams. Setting the connection-speed option to the maximum (4294967) did the trick, I'm guessing as it didn't try switching video streams to a lower quality one

```
gst-launch-1.0 souphttpsrc location=https://csm-e-nineau2-eb.bln1.yospace.com/csm/extlive/nnaprd01,prod-simulcast-mel-ch9-hls-r13.m3u8 \
 ! hlsdemux connection-speed=4294967 \
 ! tsdemux \
 ! h264parse \
 ! video/x-h264 \
 ! fakesink
```